# can I loop through parent directory and sub-directories to search for text files?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
maindir/sub1/file1.txt
maindir/sub1/file2.txt

maindir/sub2/file1.txt
maindir/sub2/file2.txt

maindir/sub3/file1.txt
maindir/sub3/file2.txt
```

I'm trying to read all the lines in these text files but I want to use a loop to search through the parent directory for any text files if it is possible. Instead of writing down the absolute path for each file.

Update:
the reading part later I'm going to implement is something like

```
while read p 
do 
echo $p 
done < file.txt
```

Comment: It depends a bit what you want to do to the files. You could easily _find_ them with a filename globbing pattern or with `find`, but the next step is depending on what you want to do with them.

Comment: I will just read all files line by line.

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 1):

```
find maindir -type f -name "*.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple loop:

```bsh
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
shopt -s globstar

for pathname in maindir/**/*.txt; do
    [ ! -f "$pathname" ] && continue
    cat "$pathname"
done
```

The above `bash` code iterates over all pathnames under `maindir` that end in `.txt`.  The names that do not correspond to regular files (or symbolic links to regular files) are skipped (that's what `continue` does, with the accompanying test).  The rest are passed to `cat` for line-by-line output.

The shell options set at the top do the following things:

- `dotglob`: enables globbing patterns to match hidden names.
- `nullglob`: removes a globbing pattern completely if it does not match. Ordinarily, non-matching globbing patterns are kept in their unexpanded form.
- `globstar`: Enables the use of `**`, which works a bit like `*` but that allows matching across `/` in pathnames.  In other words, it allows for "recursive" matching down into subdirectories.

You may replace `cat "$pathname"` with any processing that you need to do to `"$pathname"`.

---

With `find`:

```bsh
find maindir -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} +
```

This does the same thing as the loop, but with three tiny differences:

1. It does not find symbolic links to regular files. Use `find` with its `-L` option to include these, e.g., `find -L maindir ...`, but note that this would also make the utility traverse symbolically linked *directories*. The GNU implementation of `find` has `-xtype` that you could use in place of `-type` to test the type of the thing referred to if the current pathname is a symbolic link.
2. It calls `cat` with as many found files as possible at once.
3. It may present the data in another (unsorted) order than the loop (which sorts the found files in lexicographical order).

You may replace

```
-exec cat {} +
```

with the more generic

```
-exec sh -c 'for pathname do ...; done' sh {} +
```

where `...` should be replaced by whatever processing of `"$pathname"` that you require.

Comment: thanks so much that's exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate it.

Comment: `find -L` would also have the side effect of following symlinks when descending the directory tree (bash before 4.3 also did that with its `**/`). GNU `find` has a `-xtype f` would be more adequate here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas To be honest, I thought `**/` in `bash` resolved symbolic links. It seemed logical since `*/` does. (I'm not a day-to-day `bash` user).

Comment: But then it would be unusable. zsh/yash/tcsh have `***` to follow symlinks but not bash. It's unfortunate that no shell offers you easy options to exclude symlinks in `pattern/something`.